# Como imprimir en una impresora de tikect desde PHP

Tags: php, impresora

Estoy tratando de imprimir en una impresora termica desde `PHP`,usando la librería `Printer` de PHP. El código funciona, pero no imprime nada en la impresora, sin embargo en las tareas de la impresora si se esta imprimiendo un archivo en cola.

**¿Alguien puede ayudarme a corregir mi problema?.**

Les dejo el código:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;

$nombre_impresora = "XP-450B";
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector($nombre_impresora);
$printer = new Printer($connector);

$printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
$printer -> cut();

$printer -> close();
```

Comment: Las preguntas en busca de recomendaciones sobre recursos terminan cerradas

Comment: Creo que lo estas enfocando mal, mas bien diria que lo que tienes que hacer darle el formato que quieras con css <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" /> Otra cosa es que no quieras abrir el cuadro de diálogo de impresión, que tengas algún requerimiento más como que se imprima directamente, en ese caso, puedes mirar este ejemplo
[impresion-en-impresora-pos-desde-php](https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/php/impresion-en-impresora-pos-desde-php/1049694518/) La librería Printer si no estoy confundido es muy antigua y solo funciona con PHP5 o anterior

Comment: @CarlosSalgado he leido la publicación de la página que mencionas y logro notar que usan `printer` y no me ha funcionado, ya que es lo que trato de resolver.